# Files.walk doesn't seem to go into sub folders Java

Tags: java, path, stream

I have this function which is supposed to get all files ending with .bak in a folder and its subfolder, but when I debug it it says it has a depth of one which I guess means it does have sub folders? But nextstage says null and it only get the files in the localPath but not the ones in the sub folders.

here is the code

```
  private static List<FileInfo> listBackupFilesInLocalDir(String localPath, Predicate<String> fileNamePredicate) {
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(localPath))) {
        return files.filter(p -> fileNamePredicate.test(p.getFileName().toString()))
                    .map(p -> new FileInfo(p.getFileName().toString(), p.toFile().length()))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error listing directories", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

this is the method call that calls the above method with the predicate and so on

```
listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localPath, s -> s.endsWith(".bak"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
Not sure what the filtering predicate does (as code not included) but such code should work (I just replaced predicate with naive string comparison):

```
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(localPath))) {
        return files.filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".png"))
                    .map(p -> new FileInfo(p.getFileName().toString(), p.toFile().length()))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Please make sure that:

1. Your FileInfo class (not included here) implements Comparable (for
   `sorted()`)
2. Your filtering predicate works correctly

Comment: Please see my answer above: your predicate is incorrect:
`listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localPath, s -> s.endsWith(".bak"));`
you check path ending - get filename & convert it toString first

Comment: i have change it to  files.filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".bak")) but still only gets main folder files

Answer (score 0):

It seems predicate issue or exception on map file line.

```
try {
       Files.walk(Paths.get(localPath)).filter(Files::isRegularFile)
       .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
       .filter(file ->file.toString().endsWith(".bak"))
       .map(p -> new FileInfo(p.getFileName().toString(), p.toFile().length()))
       .forEach(path -> {
                    System.out.println(path.toString());
       });
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can directly filter file extension using endsWith method.

Please note .sorted() can cause ClassCastException.

If you want returned as list just remove forEach and add .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I edited with the method call and i dont get any exception or anything it runs and only give the files that are not in folders

Comment: Do you want the output files in respective folders? Walk will iterate through directory and subdirectories and saving the file info in the list where filter condition is true.

Comment: i want to iterate throu the directroy and all directories in it and add all files with .bak to the list

Comment: Please see the modified answer, you can add or remove filters as needed. You don't need to pass predicate as parameter.